# Save price as decimal or string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have an ASP.NET web project. I have a "price" field in my database, which is defined as decimal.

When the user inserts price in a textbox, the string from textbox is saved in the "price" field (I force the user to input only digits).

All data is presented in a ListView. The issue is when the user doesn't provide any value (empty textbox), I get an exception.

I can understand why this happens: because it can't cast an empty string to the decimal type. If the user didn't provide any value, I want to present an empty field in the ListView. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Validation? Check your textbox is not empty and check it's a valid decimal with `decimal.TryParse`? What have you tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: your field in the DB is defined as not null... Change this field column to Nullable or Add validation in the server that you must define value for price

Comment: You need to check in javascript or on server side. If value if empty then just enter 0.00

Comment: and you could also use decimal.TryParse() to define both a default and ensure that you don't store something that doesn't convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to have a default value 0.00 than an empty or null value. If user did not provide any value, validate it and convert the value of the textbox to 0.00.

If you don't want this suggestion check your DB then `allow null` the decimal field.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is your own logical validation. However you can set your price field to nullable or check your textbox if has no value then set your price to 0.00